# Understanding bias-variance tradeoff decomposition

Tags: regression, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, bias-variance-tradeoff

This is the formula  :

$E[(Y−f^2)]=σ^2 +Bias^2[f^]+Var[f^]$
What i cant understand , the expectation is over the training Set  for a fixed $x_0$ , thus the
$E(ϵ^2) =E(ϵ(x_0)^2) = ϵ(x_0)^2$   and not  $σ^2$  because for a given $x_0$ we have a unique ϵ  and this term is not random anymore because  any change in the dataset will not affect this term for a specific $x_0$ .

I'm confused

Comment: Welcome to CV! Note that this site has builtin latex capability (MathJax).

Comment: I added some LaTeX formatting for you, but it still needs more editing. I'm not completely sure what you wanted.

Comment: My problem is related to  the var of the noise , this formula is decomposed for a fixed xo  , therefore  the var of the noise at that given point or vector should be constant

Answer (score 1):

Let us define some terms first. Let $Y$ be the deterministic target that we want to estimate, let $X$ be a random sample, let $f$ be an estimator, and let $\widehat Y = f(X)$ be an estimate. Let the estimation error be $e = Y - f(X) = Y - \widehat Y$. Because $X$ is random, then so is $e$. The *bias* of the estimate $\widehat Y$ is
\begin{align}
\text{Bias}\left(\widehat Y\right) &= Y - E\left[\widehat Y\right] \\
&= E\left[Y - \widehat Y\right] \\
&= E[e]
\end{align}
and the variance of $\widehat Y$ is
\begin{align}
\text{Var}\left(\widehat Y\right) &= \text{Var}(Y - e) \\
&= \text{Var}(e)
\end{align}
Therefore, the bias and variance of $\widehat Y$ are equal to the mean and variance of $e$ respectively. Finally, the *mean squared error* (MSE) is $E[e^2]$. However, we know that for any random variable $Z$, $E[Z^2] = \text{Var}(Z) + E[Z]^2$. So, we have
\begin{align}
E[e^2] &= \text{Var}(e) + E[e]^2 \\
&= \text{Var}\left(\widehat Y\right) + \text{Bias}\left(\widehat Y\right)^2
\end{align}
Note that the terms "bias" and "variance" are only applicable when $Y$ is deterministic.